# Drupal6: I need to customize file upload links in node edit form

Tags: drupal, cck

I am customizing the node/add and node/edit forms of a content type with a form_alter. In my content type, there is a file field that permits to upload files to the content.
What I would like to do is to customize the file box by changing the link to the file that is composed at runtime with Ajax. How can I do it without modifying Drupal core?

Comment: You mean you want to allow either a file **upload** or a link/url to an **existing** file?

Comment: No, i want to change the URL of the uploaded file (from http://sitename/sites/default/files/123.jpg to http://sitename/index.php?q=my_function/123.jpg

Comment: Files need a physical location on the server -- would you like the file to be uploaded normally but accessible at the new link? I suppose a broader question would be: what is the end result you're looking for? What is `my_function` doing? I think I could suggest some more straightforward ways of accomplishing this without hacking the node form.

Comment: are you trying to obfuscate the link created in the node/add node/edit form? some reasons why might be helpful as there might be other solutions available to you

Comment: exactly, i need to change the link from sites/default/files/private/name.jpg to another url because private directory will not be available as url due to htaccess directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Private Files directory should not be in the docroot. Hiding it with a .htaccess rule will not work, as you point out in a comment.

Say you have Drupal in `/var/www/sites/example.com/`, then you should not store your private files under that directory; `/var/www/sites/example.com/sites/default/private/files/` is just plain wrong.

You should, instead store the files where apache will not serve them, but can read them. E.g. in `/var/www/files/example.com/`. Then change the setting in Drupal to use that *absolute* path.

If you are running a large(r) site, you will probably want to store your files on a dedicated mount (drive, NFS etc.), say `/media/nfs-example-com/`.

Comment: For future reference: this is *only* valid when files are set to private.

Comment: GREAT!! I was becoming crazy when Drupal had set up everything. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: In addition, make very sure that apache has read *and* write rules in that directory. The best option is to `chmod ug+rw -R /var/www/files/example.com` and to `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/files/example.com`, where www-data is the apache-user on ubuntu/debian; and is apache on CentOS/RedHat.

Answer (score 0):

Try Filefield Paths:

> The FileField Paths module extends the default functionality of Drupals core Upload module, the FileField module and many other File Upload modules by adding the ability to use node tokens in destination paths and filenames.

http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths

Comment: I tried it but cannot find a solution to my problem; i'll try to explain it: in my content type i have a file field that uploads files to sites/default/files/private. private directory is protected by .htaccess to deny access when user puts direct link from browser. I've made a url like index.php?q=my_function/file.jpg; in function my_function i check the user and, if authorized, let the file to be downloaded. The problem is that when i upload the file, Drupal puts the link to http://...../sites/default/files/private/file.jpg that does not run due to htaccess directive. I need to change it

Comment: Ahhh, are you meaning to protect yourself from external hotlinking to your files by excluding that dir in .htaccess? If so a better way to block hotlinking might be thru a rewrite directive like so: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]